# Are there compelling reasons not to organize the elementary particles by charge and spin?

Tags: particle-physics, charge, quantum-spin, standard-model, elementary-particles

I don't like the way the standard model is currently displayed (see second picture for reference).
It does a poor job of abstracting the information into something understandable. As far as I understand, the three major quanta of elementary particles are mass, spin, and charge, with the latter two lending themselves to table-ifying (like so)

[image: My idea for a table of Elementary Particles]

To me, this makes more sense than most images I've seen (on Wikipedia, for example), but I'm wondering if there are major pieces of information missing from a table like this?

[image: Current representation of standard model (a la Wikipedia)]

Comment: There is no standard way to display the Standard Model. Why do you think charge is so important, when two of the three interactions in the Standard Model have nothing to do with charge?

Comment: Your alternative table of the Elementary Particles of the Standard Model emphasizes the charge and spin relationships and includes masses, which are important ways to categorize some of the particle and force properties. Your table on the right relates all 3 forces and their action on each of the particles.  I didn't see any omissions.  Is there any force or particle you were unable to include in the two charts?

Comment: You have stated, "the three major quanta of elementary particles are mass, spin, and charge." Certainly, mass is a quanta in the sense that each particle has a specific mass.  But, as you note, mass does not table-ify well, which implies a more fundamental property that gives each particle its unique mass.  Listing the masses of each particle is good for reference, but there is still something missing.  Why do the Standard Model Particles have their mass?  Is there a theory that predicts the mass of each of the Standard Model Particles? Current theory could not predict the Higgs mass.

Comment: Your table suggests that the up-quark is an antiparticle. Makes sense +2/3 :)

Comment: There's more than one kind of charge. There's electric charge, weak hypercharge, and color charge. Why is electric charge singled out?

Comment: I used charge and spin because they seem to be what classifies each particle. Other charges, like color charge, hypercharge, strangeness, bottomness, etc., either a.) aren't constant for any of the quarks (color charge is always changing), making them useless for classification, b.) have multiple values for subsets of the particle (weak hypercharge is different depending on handedness of the quark), or c.) strangeness/bottomness and the like are unique to the 2nd and 3rd generations of fermions, which is seen here in the separation of the generations.

Comment: @G. Smith It may only be affected by one of the interactions, but electric charge is integral to defining what particle it is. Up, charm and top quarks _always_ have electric charge of +2/3, and a given fermion with electric charge +2/3 is guaranteed to be one of those three. Electric charge is a fundamental part of each particle, and an important part of identifying them.

Comment: Possible duplicate by OP: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/469089/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic Not really, granted, they are related. The first question was asking why we use the current table, what elements make it useful, and why it's organized the way it is. This question is proposing something different and asking what the problems/limitations of this specific representation might be.

Comment: Walker, keep it up.